# How to run application without focus? (alternative way)

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
end;
```

Unfortunately, the above code does not work well in conjunction with an activated jvTrayIcon component (`tvVisibleTaskBar:=false`). The Main form remains visible with missing UI elements:

[image]

Comment: what does this have to do with window activation?  Sounds like a window painting issue instead.  Have you tried simply calling the form's `Invalidate()` or `Refresh()` method after it is displayed?

Comment: JvTrayIcon is configured to not show main form (tvVisibleTaskBar:=false).
It works fine without ShowWindow(Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
. I would like to know how to run my application with active JvTrayIcon and without stolen focus.

Comment: You are asking for support with a 3rd party component.  Have you contacted the author yet for help?

Comment: I think that JVCL is no longer supported.

Comment: @Atak_Snajpera: [Web news portal](http://newsportal.delphi-jedi.org/thread_frameset.php?group=jedi.jvcl). Also, [NNTP groups](nntp://news.delphi-jedi.org).

Comment: @Rudy Hmm, looks like Stack Overflow's markdown implementation never accounted for protocols other than `http` or `https`...

Comment: @Jerry: yes, I noticed, but decided to leave it that way. It is pretty readable anyway.

Comment: Activate the trayicon after you've called ShowWindow.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting

```
Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := False;
Application.ShowMainForm := false;
```

before your

```
Application.CreateForm(TForm1, Form1);
```

in the .dpr-file